# Is it possible to get values inside two auto generated keys without knowing them in Firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have added some values under every auto generated keys and also added a child (example-student) corresponding to each key. Then I have added auto generated key with this child (student) and values. Now question is how I can get the values from this sequence? I am using model class for students.. Is it possible?

[image: Here is my database screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read this data, and then process it in your app, you can do something like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getRef();
DatabaseReference lecturesRef = rootRef.child("lectures");
lecturesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot lecureSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
      System.out.println(lecureSnapshot.getKey());
      System.out.println(lecureSnapshot.child("lectureDate").getValue(String.class));
      for (DataSnapshot studentSnapshot: lecureSnapshot.child("students").getChildren()) {
        System.out.println(studentSnapshot.getKey());
        System.out.println(studentSnapshot.child("id").getValue(String.class));
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    throw databaseError.toException();
  }
}
```

The above code shows how to:

- Get a snapshot of the value at a specific location.
- Loop over the child nodes under that location, in cases where you don't know the keys of those child nodes.
- Get the unknown key of the child node.
- Get the value of a specific property of each child node.
- Loop over nested children.